# How can I get the parent entity object and is an optional relationship possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

My current Core Data implementation has no relationships, so very bad and difficult to get the info when needed.

I'm going to go to this kind of relationship:

patient --one-to-many--> doctor --one-to-many--> schedules

Now imagine you have an `NSManagedObject` from schedules, how do I get his parent doctor managed object?

Can I still use the schedules entity on its own (schedules without a relationship to a doctor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it, but this is not a recommended method.

1: Get array of doctor objects.

2: Iterate through doctor objects, for each doctor object get it's array of schedules and iterate through each schedule to find a match.

The correct method is to have an inverse relationship from schedules to doctor, which is exactly what Apple says (without which xcode flags a warning too)!

Here is the piece of code. Here I am assuming that each schedule object has an 'scheduleId' inorder to identify each of them.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getContext {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    return managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSArray *)getAllDoctors {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self getContext];
    NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Doctor" 
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:messageEntity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *allDoctors = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return allDoctors;
}
- (Doctor *)pickDoctorScheduledFor:(NSString *)scheduleId {
    NSArray *allDoctors = [self getAllDoctors];

    for (Doctor *doctor in allDoctors) {

        NSArray *schedulesForThisDoctor = [doctor.schedules allObjects]; // one to many relation!
        for (Schedule *schedule in schedulesForThisDoctor) {
            if ([schedule. scheduleId isEqualToString: scheduleId]) {
                return doctor;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Could you give a small example of how the syntax looks like then. (I couldn't find it anywhere.)

Comment: Thanks but I meant an example if a reverse relationship is specified?

Comment: Reverse relationship works exactly the same way as other relationship. If you have, say a one to many relationship from A to B, add a relationship from B to A in xcdatatmodel editor and mention this relation as the inverse of other relation. At the time you auto generate .h .m files for these entities you will find that A will have 2 methods 1: addObject:(B *)value 2: addObjects:(NSSet *)vaules and B will have a reference to A. Just call these functions every time you create an instance of B. For eg. for a new B, call [A addObject:B] (Child relation) and B.referenceToA = A (Parent relation)

Comment: Thank you ;-) "At the time you auto generate .h .m" Never done this, was allways doing [mObj valueForKey:@""].

Comment: @Pieter Melcow! Happy coding ;-)